# Bootstrap tab code loading with js when DOM gets ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap tabs and I load the initial active tab with the http request. When I click on the tabs js works fine. But I'd like to call some other js on the initially loaded content and for that to work I need to send over the `data: {tab: target}`, so I decided to load the initial tab content with js when the page gets loaded (like the others get loaded on clicking the tab, just the trigger event is different).

The problem is I don't know how I could trigger the AJAX right after the page gets loaded and how to organize my code properly for the different kind of triggers (loading/clicking).

Here is the working code when clicking on tabs:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
  var target = $(this).data("activetab");
  var href = $(this).data("link");
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: href,
    data: {tab: target},
    dataType: "script"
  });
});
```

html:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#filestab" aria-controls="filestab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-link = "<%= get_files_user_common_medias_path(@user)%>" data-activetab="file">Files</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#linkstab" aria-controls="linkstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-link = "<%= get_links_user_common_medias_path(@user)%>" data-activetab="link">Links</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#calendarstab" aria-controls="calendarstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-link = "<%= common_medias_user_common_medias_path(@user)%>" data-activetab="calendar">Calendar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What if you just after the jQuery code you have do this `$('.nav-tabs .active a').click()`. That will trigger a `click` event in the first tab, that should trigger the `shown.bs.tab`.

Comment: That would result double click (which can work), but I guess there should be a cleaner solution without sending to request to the db? Any other ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with `without sending to request to the db`? Don't you wanna load the first tab with AJAX too?

Comment: I mean for the first tab on initial load it would be one request, but if I click on another tab then it will get the request twice, won't it? (Since at the moment with the current code the rest of the tabs already get the request once on clicking)

Comment: Just to be clear: You want the first tab to be loaded by AJAX after the page gets loaded and the rest of the tabs by AJAX on click? All of them using the same function that you already have. But you are worried because every time you click on a tab it will loaded again. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes I want the first tab (#filestab) loaded by AJAX without doing anything then if I click on other tabs, those get loaded by AJAX as well, and if I click again on the deafult tab(#filestab) then that should be reloaded by AJAX again. My problem is that currently some of other js functions not working on page load, just if I click on another tab then click again on (#filestab). It's because I send over some params 'data:{tab: target}' with this AJAX call which are needed for the other function to run.

Comment: I made an edit in my answer. It wasn't as straightforward as I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the first tab to be loaded by AJAX and every time you click on a tab to be reloaded, leave what you have and after that add:

```
$('[href="#filestab"]').tab('show');
```

And you need -apparently- to remove the `class="active"` from the first tab. Otherwise it doesn't trigger the `show` event because it is already selected.

[Bootstrap tab methods](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-methods).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypt1cpyx/).

Comment: with the last modification it works ;); I tried to call on everything but '[href="#filestab"]'. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad. Glad I could help.